# How to remove Accents (é,ç,ã,ò) in {{slug}} Netlify CMS

Tags: javascript, yaml, content-management-system, netlify

I have this in my config.yml:

```
slug: "{{slug}}"
    encoding: "ascii"
    clean_accents: true
```

But when my title is some like this *(in PT-BR)*: **“Doce de paçoca é bom!”** I need this way: **“doce-de-pacoca-e-bom”** but I get this result on *filename.md/url*: **“doce-de-paçoca-é-bom”**. Any possible to remove this automatically without creating a field named slug and doing manually?

EDIT:

this is my *config.yml*, basically it is the backend of **Netlify CMS**.

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: main
media_folder: "_site/assets/uploads/destaques"
public_folder: "/assets/uploads/destaques/"
collections:
  - name: "games" # Used in routes, e.g., /admin/collections/blog
    label: "Games" # Used in the UI
    folder: "store" # The path to the folder where the documents are stored
    create: true # Allow users to create new documents in this collection
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    fields: # The fields for each document, usually in front matter
      - {label: "Layout", name: "layout", widget: "hidden", default: "layouts/store.njk"}
      - {label: "Id", name: "id", widget: "number"}
      - {label: "Youtube", name: "youtube", widget: "string", required: false}
      - {label: "Titulo", name: "title", widget: "string"}
```

The {{slug}} takes the Title label and make it url friendly, but i need to remove the accents and it do not remove...

have some titles that have words like **"ç,á,é,ô..."** but i need to remove it and replace to **"c,a,e,o..."**.

Comment: I made a edit to clarify the question...